# PHP DOM - Problem loading YouTube Embed Code

Tags: php, url, dom, youtube

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$string = "<object width=\"425\" height=\"350\">
               <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/1OtdDqF5rnI&autoplay=0\"></param>
               <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>
               <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/1OtdDqF5rnI&autoplay=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"425\" height=\"350\"></embed>
           </object>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($string);
```

When I load the string i get the following errors:

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /mnt/FS-2/Critical/Media/Private/Website/Online/blitz1up.com/application/controllers/articles.php on line 303: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 2
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /mnt/FS-2/Critical/Media/Private/Website/Online/blitz1up.com/application/controllers/articles.php on line 303: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 4
```

I have narrowed the cause down to the YouTube URLs but am unsure of the best method to resolve this error. So any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs contain ampersands, which should be encoded as `&amp;` when not used for declaring entities. The parser assumes `&autoload` will start a new entitiy but it is never terminated with a semicolon.

For working with the HTML, consider loading the fragment with `loadHTML()`; and disable errors for that part:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_clear_errors();
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

The above would work with `loadXML` too.

Comment: Cool... changing the ampersands to &amp has fixed the issue. Thank you.