# PHP error when loading an RSS feed with "&" in the data

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

My task is loading an XML RSS feed with PHP. I solved it so far, but I randomly encountered a problem the other day: If the news contains the ampersand character (&) in the .xml file, I will get a PHP error. I understand the error and all, but I couldn't find a proper solution so far.

```
$URL = 'http://somesite.com/file.xml';
$DOM = new DomDocument();
$DOM->load($URL);

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): EntityRef: expecting ';' in file
```

I tried different things like:

```
$DOM->recover = TRUE;
$DOM->load($URL);
```

The to be loaded .xml files are in UTF-8.

Comment: have you tried $dom->validateOnParse = false; ?

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php

Comment: tell the person providing the feed to fix their xml?

Comment: "Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Validation failed: no DTD found !EntityRef: expecting ';' in file" is the new error.

Comment: yes, you should set the validation to false. I missed this as I have copied it out of the manual

Comment: Doesn't have any effect :/ thx anyways!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOM - Problem loading YouTube Embed Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510574/php-dom-problem-loading-youtube-embed-code)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use urlencode function in php ,also you can find those special characters and replace that with space or something else